# How to pass length for CAST dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2008, casting, trim

This seems like a trivial syntax issue that I'm unaware of. I would like to define a function on the lines of trimming some data based on the allowed limit for column.

Here's some sample code that works.

```
DECLARE @value nvarchar(max) = ' Test string abc '
DECLARE @length integer = 10
DECLARE @trimValue nvarchar(max) = @value
SELECT @trimValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(@value AS nvarchar(10))))
SELECT @trimValue
```

returns 'Test str'

Now I want to pass in that casting length dynamically. How can I do this?

```
 SELECT @trimValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(@value AS nvarchar(@length))))
```

Comment: With `sp_executesql` and an output parameter I suspect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use LEFT in this case since it is a string, otherwise you need to do it dynamically

```
DECLARE @value nvarchar(max) = ' Test string abc '
DECLARE @length integer = 10

DECLARE @trimValue nvarchar(max) = @value
SELECT @trimValue = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@value)),@length)
SELECT @trimValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this?  The overhead for all VARCHAR and NVARCHAR is the same, up to lengths of 8000 and 4000 respectively.

The real problem is that the cast itself won't really work, because it will be recast into the length of the variable as declared.

Answer (score 0):

an example of how to use sp_executesql to dynamically set the size:

```
DECLARE @value nvarchar(max) = ' Test string abc '
DECLARE @length integer = 10
DECLARE @trimValue nvarchar(max) = @value
DECLARE @parameters NVARCHAR(100)

declare @sql nvarchar(200)
set @sql = N'select @trimValueOUT = LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(''' + @value + ''' AS nvarchar(' + cast(@length as varchar(15)) + '))))'
SET @parameters = N'@trimValueOUT nvarchar(' + cast(@length as varchar(15)) + ') output'

--print @sql
--print @parameters
execute sp_executesql @sql, @parameters, @trimValueOUT = @trimValue output
SELECT @trimValue
```